# Mongo Upsert with values of find $in

Tags: mongodb

I have to run mongo updates by querying that the user id is in an array. Is it possible to upsert any values not in the array?

Eg:

```
db.collection.update({
 userId:{
      $in:['1','2', '3']
    }
 }, 
 {$set: {score:30}}, 
 {upsert:true})
```

If I run this query I get one new doc with _id and score. What I'd like to do is have a new doc for each userId not present in the userId array:

```
[{userId:1, score:30, _id:...}, {userId:2, score: 30, _id: ...}, ...]
```

Is this possible in mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be done. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior) states:

> If upsert is true and no document matches the query criteria, update() inserts a *single* document.