# Upsert a document with value from filter

Tags: database, mongodb, go

I have a collection with following structure in MongoDB:

```
{
  "userId": String,
  "refs": Set<String>
}
```

I need to update the collections with those documents. I want to add to `refs` a new string, for users that are in the filter `$in`.
But, if the user is not exists I need to "upsert" him.

In code (golang) it looks like this:

```golang
filter := bson.M{
    "userId": bson.M{
        "$in:": tokens // tokens is []string
    }
}

update := bson.M{
    "$addToSet": bson.M{
        "refs": newReference
    }
}

ctx, _ := newDbOperationContext()
_, err := driver.UpdateMany(ctx, filter, update)
```

So, for existing users it works ok, the reference is added. But, for users that not exists nothing happen.

I set in `driver.UpdateMany(bson, bson, opts...)` opts to `options.UpdateOptions.SetUpsert(true)"`, but as a result I got a document without userId:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "refs": ["new_reference"]
}
```

So, my question is, how to upsert the new values with `userId` field.

The scale is like 2*10^6 users to update, so I would like to do that using batch request. Creating using "one by one" and updating him is not an option here, I think.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to previous questions in SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794018/mongo-upsert-with-values-of-find-in) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431213/mongodb-upsert-multiple-documents-at-the-same-time-with-key-like-in) it does not seem possible to perform multiple `upserts` using only the `$in` operator because it will insert only [a single document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists-upsert) (the one matching the filter):

> If no document matches the query criteria, db.collection.update() inserts *a single document*.

So as mentioned by @Kartavya the best is to perform multiple write operations using `BulkWrite`.

For that you need to append an upsert op (=[WriteModel](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#WriteModel)) for each of the users in `tokens` as a filter, and for all you can use the same `$addToSet` update operation:

```
tokens := [...]string{"userId1", "userId3"}
newRef := "refXXXXXXX"

// all docs can use the same $addToSet update operation
updateOp := bson.D{{"$addToSet", bson.D{{"refs", newRef}}}}

// we'll append one update for each userId in tokens as a filter
upserts := []mongo.WriteModel{}
for _, t := range tokens {
    upserts = append(
        upserts,
        mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.D{{"userId", t}}).SetUpdate(updateOp).SetUpsert(true))
}

opts := options.BulkWrite().SetOrdered(false)
res, err := col.BulkWrite(context.TODO(), upserts, opts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your use case, I think the best solution will be the following :

Since you have a high scale and wish to make batch requests, it is best to use BulkWrite : The db.collection.bulkWrite() method provides the ability to perform bulk insert, update, and remove operations.
 Example : https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#example-Collection-BulkWrite

This uses UpdateOne Model but it supports UpdateMany Model as well. It also a function of SetUpsert(true) 
Now for the _id field : Your updated/upserted document should have _id field for the new document to have that _id field else mongoDb auto-generates an _id field while inserting the document if your upsert document does not have _id field

I think, it will not be much of a pain to have _id field in your documents, so that way your problem is solved.

Regarding the scale, I suggest using BulkWrite with UpdateOne or UpdateMany models.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem is that those documents must have `userId` field. It may be saved in `_id` field, but it's must be the userId generated somewhere else.

Comment: Have the userId a part of the update document ? 
If you use bulkWrite with UpdateOne, this will still be a batch request.
And if there are 2*10^6 requests per minute, I dont think this will lead to much impact.

Answer (score 0):

In case of upsert if the document is not present then only the updator part of query is going to insert in the database. So that's why your output is like that. You can see [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior)